# How to `use` function scoped structs?

Tags: rust

Consider the following contrived example:

```rust
mod Parent {
    fn my_fn() {
        struct MyStruct;

        mod Inner {
            use super::MyStruct; //Error: unresolved import `super::MyStruct`. No `MyStruct` in `Parent`
        }
    }
}
```

How can I import `MyStruct` here from the inner module?

---

#### Motivation

While the above is code that you'll never write manually, it is code that is useful to generate. A real-world use-case would be a derive-macro. Let's say I want this:

```rust
#[derive(Derivative)]
struct MyStruct;
```

Now it's useful to isolate the generated code in its own module, to isolate the generated code from the source code (e.g. to avoid naming collisions, leaking of `use` declarations, etc.). So I want the generated code to be something like this:

```rust
mod _Derivative_MyStruct {
    use super::MyStruct;
    impl Derivative for MyStruct { }
}
```

However, the example above fails if the struct is defined in a function, due to the problem at the top. e.g. this won't work:

```rust
fn my_fn() {
    #[derive(Derivative)];
    struct MyStruct;
}
```

as it expands into:

```rust
fn my_fn() {
    #[derive(Derivative)];
    struct MyStruct;
    mod _Derivative_MyStruct {
        use super::MyStruct; // error
        impl Derivative for MyStruct {}
    }
}
```

This is especially troublesome for doctests, as these are implicitly wrapped in a function. E.g. this will give the unresolved import problem:

````rust
/// Some interesting documentation
/// ```
/// #[derive(Derivative)]
/// struct MyStruct;
/// ```
````

Without the ability to refer to the outer scope, I either need to give up isolation, or require wrapping in modules at the call site. I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: I don't think there is any way of accessing the struct inside the nested module. Your best bet is probably to try and avoid the module. In the example you gave the module doesn't seem to have any purpose anyway, and inserting the impl directly has exactly the same effect (except that it actually works).

Comment: The module definitely has a purpose. As stated above, it isolates namespaces: `use` statements are local, and any newly introduced names (struct, enums, etc) are local. Chayim's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73515842/532901) helps to avoid naming conflicts, but unfortunately use statements still aren't localized. Conflicts here can be avoided by using fully qualified names in the generated code, but this hurts readability of (already complex) macro code.

Answer (score 1):

This is [issue #79260](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/79260). I don't think there is a solution.

However, you can define the nested items inside an unnamed `const` (`const _: () = { /* code */ };`) instead of a module. This prevents name collisions and is the idiomatic thing to do in macros that need to define names. Do note however that this does not have a way to refer to items inside the `const` from outside it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately the `const` approach still doesn't fully isolate namespaces - specifically `use` is still from the outer scope - but at least it's better than nothing.

Comment: @Tiddo True, but you can override them.